# 2 img in the same div wont separate

Tags: html, image

I have a page where I have a div that defines a space where I have a specific color-gradient showing. To make sure my images and text show up they have to be inside of the div, obviously. However I have 2 images and no matter how much padding i give one, the other image still stays in-line with it.

```html
<!-- background gradient and setting up the display field -->
<div style="width: 320px; height: 480px; background: linear-gradient(#2F6DBA, #97E8DF)">
  <h1 style="font-family: 'AR BONNIE'; font-size: 60px; color: ffffff; padding-top: 50px; text-align: center">
   test
  </h1>
  <a style="text-decoration: none" class="imageLink" href="link1.htm">
    <!-- first img -->

    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b4/Topeka-leaderboard.svg/120px-Topeka-leaderboard.svg.png" style="width: 90px; height: 90px" />

  </a>
  <a style="text-decoration: none" class="imageLink" href="link2.htm">
    <!-- img2 -->
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/128/play-icon.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; padding-top: 60px" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: are you looking something like this ?? https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/q2jd1osv/1/ 
actually a bit confused that's why need to sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of formatting you are looking for?

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- background gradient and setting up the display field -->
<div style="width: 320px; height: 480px; background: linear-gradient(#2F6DBA, #97E8DF)">
  <h1 style="font-family: 'AR BONNIE'; font-size: 60px; color: ffffff; padding-top: 50px; text-align: center">
   test
  </h1>
  <a style="text-decoration: none" class="imageLink" href="link1.htm">
    <!-- first img -->

    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b4/Topeka-leaderboard.svg/120px-Topeka-leaderboard.svg.png" style="width: 90px; height: 90px" />

  </a>
  <a style="text-decoration: none" class="imageLink" href="link2.htm">
    <!-- img2 -->
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/128/play-icon.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; padding-top: 60px" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm bit confused about what you want to achieve so I placed two example here- 
1st One [LiveOnFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/o9u58h5c/)

```html
    
    <div style="width: 320px; height: 480px; background: linear-gradient(#2F6DBA, #97E8DF)">
  <h1 style="font-family: 'AR BONNIE'; font-size: 60px; color: ffffff; padding-top: 50px; text-align: center">
        test
    </h1>
  <a style="text-decoration: none" class="imageLink" href="link1.html">
    <!-- first img -->

    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b4/Topeka-leaderboard.svg/120px-Topeka-leaderboard.svg.png" style="width: 90px; height: 90px; margin:0 auto;display:block;" />

  </a>
  <a style="text-decoration: none" class="imageLink" href="link2.htm">
    <!-- img2 -->
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/128/play-icon.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; padding-top: 60px; margin:0 auto;display:block;" />
  </a>
</div>
```

2nd One [LiveOnFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/q2jd1osv/1/)

```html
<div style="width: 320px; height: 480px; background: linear-gradient(#2F6DBA, #97E8DF)">
  <h1 style="font-family: 'AR BONNIE'; font-size: 60px; color: ffffff; padding-top: 50px; text-align: center">
        test
    </h1>
  <a style="text-decoration: none" class="imageLink" href="link1.htm">
    <!-- first img -->

    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b4/Topeka-leaderboard.svg/120px-Topeka-leaderboard.svg.png" style="width: 90px; height: 90px;" />

  </a>
  <a style="text-decoration: none" class="imageLink" href="link2.htm">
    <!-- img2 -->
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/128/play-icon.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;  float:right;" />
  </a>
</div>
```